# Is there a way to train a Tensorflow Keras' model manually without using the fit method or I'm freaking out?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've just started to learn Tensorflow and Keras and I wondering if there is another option, more manually, to train the model without using fit method.

I want to do the optimisation pass manually: I want to update the parameters by myself using my own loss function and updating these parameters with the loss that I have compute.

Is there any way to do that or I'm freaking out?

I'm asking this because I want to understand more how Keras' model works and if there any way to train a network without using fit method, that looks like it does a lot of things.

Comment: Tensorflow has its official website for tutorial which fits in you require. Here's the site: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look to this tutorial: [Tensorflow - Custom training](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training).
It is explained how to create your own loss function, your custom optimizer and how to define the training loop. You have full control of the training process.

I copy here the code that may interest you the most from the tutorial:

```
# Custom loss
def loss(target_y, predicted_y):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(target_y - predicted_y))

# Define a training loop
def train(model, inputs, outputs, learning_rate):
  with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    current_loss = loss(outputs, model(inputs))
  dW, db = t.gradient(current_loss, [model.W, model.b])
  model.W.assign_sub(learning_rate * dW)
  model.b.assign_sub(learning_rate * db)

model = Model()

Ws, bs = [], []
epochs = range(10)
for epoch in epochs:
  Ws.append(model.W.numpy())
  bs.append(model.b.numpy())
  current_loss = loss(outputs, model(inputs))

  train(model, inputs, outputs, learning_rate=0.1)
  print('Epoch %2d: W=%1.2f b=%1.2f, loss=%2.5f' %
        (epoch, Ws[-1], bs[-1], current_loss))
```

That tutorial uses a very simple linear model, but it is very useful to get the idea. However, if you are interested in something more complex, check this tutorial: [Tensorflow - Custom training: walkthrough](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough#train_the_model)

```
#Create the model 
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(4,)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])

# You can define your own loss function here
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
def loss(model, x, y, training):
  # training=training is needed only if there are layers with different
  # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
  y_ = model(x, training=training)

  return loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=y_)

# Create here your gradient and optimizor
def grad(model, inputs, targets):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets, training=True)
  return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)

# Training loop 
train_loss_results = []
train_accuracy_results = []

num_epochs = 201

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  epoch_loss_avg = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
  epoch_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

  # Training loop - using batches of 32
  for x, y in train_dataset:
    # Optimize the model
    loss_value, grads = grad(model, x, y)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    # Track progress
    epoch_loss_avg.update_state(loss_value)  # Add current batch loss
    # Compare predicted label to actual label
    # training=True is needed only if there are layers with different
    # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
    epoch_accuracy.update_state(y, model(x, training=True))

  # End epoch
  train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
  train_accuracy_results.append(epoch_accuracy.result())

  if epoch % 50 == 0:
    print("Epoch {:03d}: Loss: {:.3f}, Accuracy: {:.3%}".format(epoch,
                                                                epoch_loss_avg.result(),
                                                                epoch_accuracy.result()))
```

Comment: I have tried, but I get an error: AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'trainable_variables'. I asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147370/attributeerror-model-object-has-no-attribute-trainable-variables

Comment: I've answered you in the new question