# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'trainable_variables' when model is <class 'keras.engine.training.Model'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've just started to learn Tensorflow (2.1.0), Keras (2.3.1) and Python 3.7.7.

By the way, I'm running all my code on an Anaconda Environment on Windows 7 64bit. I have also tried on an Anaconda Environment on Linux and I get the same error.

I'm following this Tensorflow's tutorial: "[Custom training: walkthrough](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough)".

Everything is ok, but when I typed this piece of code:

```
def grad(model, inputs, targets):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets, training=True)
  return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
```

I get the error:

> Instance of 'Model' has no 'trainable_variables' member

This is my model, with all of its imports:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Input, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def vgg16_encoder_decoder(input_size = (200,200,1)):
    #################################
    # Encoder
    #################################
    inputs = Input(input_size, name = 'input')

    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv1_1')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv1_2')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_1')(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv2_1')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv2_2')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_2')(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_1')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_2')(conv3)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv3_3')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_3')(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_1')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_2')(conv4)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv4_3')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_4')(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_1')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_2')(conv5)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name ='conv5_3')(conv5)
    pool5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2), name = 'pool_5')(conv5)

    #################################
    # Decoder
    #################################
    #conv1 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (2, 2), strides = 2, name = 'conv1')(pool5)

    upsp1 = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name = 'upsp1')(pool5)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv6_1')(upsp1)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv6_2')(conv6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv6_3')(conv6)

    upsp2 = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name = 'upsp2')(conv6)
    conv7 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv7_1')(upsp2)
    conv7 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv7_2')(conv7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv7_3')(conv7)
    zero1 = ZeroPadding2D(padding =  ((1, 0), (1, 0)), data_format = 'channels_last', name='zero1')(conv7)

    upsp3 = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name = 'upsp3')(zero1)
    conv8 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv8_1')(upsp3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv8_2')(conv8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv8_3')(conv8)

    upsp4 = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name = 'upsp4')(conv8)
    conv9 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv9_1')(upsp4)
    conv9 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv9_2')(conv9)

    upsp5 = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2), name = 'upsp5')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv10_1')(upsp5)
    conv10 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv10_2')(conv10)

    conv11 = Conv2D(1, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', name = 'conv11')(conv10)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv11, name = 'vgg-16_encoder_decoder')

    return model
```

I have found any reference for that attribute in [Tensorflow Keras Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) documentation.

On "[Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2 - 2. Make the code 2.0-native](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#2_use_python_objects_to_track_variables_and_losses)", say:

> If you need to aggregate lists of variables (like
>   tf.Graph.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES)), use the .variables
>   and .trainable_variables attributes of the Layer and Model objects.

The network in Tensorflow's tutorial "[Custom training: walkthrough](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough)" is:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(4,)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])
```

When I do:

```
print(type(model))
```

I get:

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>
```

But if I print the type of my network, `vgg16_encoder_decoder`, I get:

```
<class 'keras.engine.training.Model'>
```

So, **the problem is** the type of the network. I haven't say the above class, `'keras.engine.training.Model'`, before.

How can I fix this problem to let me use the attribute `trainable_variables`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `keras` library instead of `tensorflow.keras`.
When using tensorflow it is highly recommended to use its own keras implementation.

This code should works

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, ZeroPadding2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np


def vgg16_encoder_decoder(input_size = (200,200,1)):
    # Your code here (no change needed)


model = vgg16_encoder_decoder()
model.trainable_variables
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code only works on PyCharm. I've been using Visual Studio Code and it doesn't recognize any of the inputs `from tensorflow.keras...`.

Comment: Are you using the same virtual environment in both IDE? maybe you have to configure the conda environment in vscode. Check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Yes, it is using the same anaconda environment: `D:\Usuarios\VansFannel\Programas\anaconda3\envs\nifti`. If I do this on a CMD shell with nifti environment activate, ` python -c 'from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model`, I don't get any error. If I do on ipython: `from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model`, I don't get any error either. I've just started to use pyCharm. I will ask this problem here.