# Tensorflow model type is `kears.engine` instead of `tensorflow.python.keras`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am at the moment training a model in a custom training loop. Therefore I need access to `model.trainable_variables`. However my model has type `keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7fa284a24d30` instead of `tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147370/attributeerror-model-object-has-no-attribute-trainable-variables-when-model)).

So as soon as I try to grab the trainable variables I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'trainable_variables'
```

I tested the types in my script and in the terminal as follows:

```
Python 3.9.5 (default, Nov 18 2021, 16:00:48) 
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'2.8.0'
>>> print(tf.keras.models.Sequential())
<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x7f181ad64fd0>
```

which clearly should not happen.

I tried to remove keras and tensorflow and install them again using pip. I tried to remove tensorflow and keras and install only keras.

I also tried to create a new virtual environment to install everything from scratch in a clean environment but the same happens.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening and how I can access the trainable variables

Comment: You need to include the actual code to reproduce the problem, it should like you are using the wrong imports

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy what do you mean? The previous python commands are actual code. I tested the behavior in the terminal inside the virtual environment. The resulting print should be `tensorfloe.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential`. I am not concerned with the `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'trainable_variables'`. That one I know exactly where it comes from. I am only concerned about why `tf.keras.models.Sequential()` has the wrong type.

Comment: That is just a few lines, please do not repeat the problem, and I asked you the imports you are using in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The bug:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'trainable_variables'
```

was caused by a bug in the code. The script now runs properly.

Comment: Asked question and answered himself